# Extract label values from a LabelledGeneric instance

Tags: scala, case-class, shapeless, labelled-generic

Consider the following example:

```
import shapeless._

case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Boolean)
val labl = LabelledGeneric[Foo]
```

Now, the type of `labl` is (prettified)

```
LabelledGeneric[Foo] {
  type Repr =
    FieldType[Symbol @@ String("bar"), String] ::
    FieldType[Symbol @@ String("baz"), Boolean] ::
    HNil
}
```

which already conveys the information I need, i.e. the names of the case class fields.

What I'm looking for is a way to go from `labl` to something along the lines of

```
"bar" :: "baz" :: HNil
```

i.e. materializing the information contained in the singleton types into a value.

Is this possible?
I could use a macro, but I feel like I would end up rewriting something very similar to the `GenericMacros` object in shapeless, so I'm wondering whether I can leverage it directly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can obtain the keys of the record (as `Symbol`s) via `shapeless.ops.record.Keys`.

This

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.record._

case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Boolean)
val labl = LabelledGeneric[Foo]
val keys = Keys[labl.Repr].apply
println(keys)
println(keys.toList.map(_.name))
```

results in

```
'bar :: 'baz :: HNil
List(bar, baz) : List(String)
```

Comment: great, thanks! A minor note: despite what it looks like from the first println, `keys` type is not an `HList` of symbols or strings, but it also contains the tags information. I needed an `HList` of pure strings, so I had to map over the `HList` with a `Poly1` along the lines of 

    `object toName extends Poly1 {
      implicit def keyToName[A] = at[Symbol with A](_.name)
    }`