# In scala 2.13. What's the cause of the problem "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" in macro expansion?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-2.13

I'm experimenting the macro in this answer:

[How to get the name of a class as a string literal at compile time using shapeless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837880/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-class-as-a-string-literal-at-compile-time-using-shapele)

The following macro is used to extract type description from a type parameter:

```
  object typeablePoly extends Poly1 {

    implicit def cse[A](
        implicit
        typeable: Typeable[A]
    ): Case[A] = macro cseImpl[A]

    def cseImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context)(typeable: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
      import c.universe._
      val tpA = weakTypeOf[A]

      val describe = c.untypecheck(q"$typeable.describe")

      val str = c.eval(
        c.Expr[String](describe)
      )
      q"null.asInstanceOf[FieldTypes.typeablePoly.Case.Aux[$tpA, _root_.shapeless.labelled.FieldType[$str, $tpA]]]"
    }
  }
```

When I try to call it explicitly:

```
    val cc2 = typeablePoly.cse[Map[String, Int]]

    TypeViz.infer(cc2).should_=:=()
```

I got the following compilation error:

```
[Error] /home/peng/git/shapesafe/core/src/test/scala/org/shapesafe/m/FieldTypesSpec.scala:16: exception during macro expansion: 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.apply(LinearSeq.scala:117)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.apply$(LinearSeq.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateOrRelink$1(Importers.scala:183)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importSymbol(Importers.scala:223)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateType(Importers.scala:237)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importType(Importers.scala:298)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateType(Importers.scala:237)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importType(Importers.scala:298)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateSymbol(Importers.scala:141)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.cachedRecreateSymbol$1(Importers.scala:158)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.$anonfun$importSymbol$6(Importers.scala:207)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.orElse(Symbols.scala:2644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateOrRelink$1(Importers.scala:206)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importSymbol(Importers.scala:223)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.$anonfun$recreateType$5(Importers.scala:261)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Scopes$Scope.foreach(Scopes.scala:455)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateType(Importers.scala:261)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importType(Importers.scala:298)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter$$anon$3.complete(Importers.scala:91)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.completeInfo(Symbols.scala:1568)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1531)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$9.scala$reflect$runtime$SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$super$info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:209)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:158)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol.info$(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:158)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SynchronizedSymbols$SynchronizedSymbol$$anon$9.info(SynchronizedSymbols.scala:209)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateOrRelink$1(Importers.scala:180)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importSymbol(Importers.scala:223)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreatedTreeCompleter(Importers.scala:312)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.$anonfun$importTree$1(Importers.scala:432)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.tryFixup(Importers.scala:61)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importTree(Importers.scala:433)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateTree(Importers.scala:397)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importTree(Importers.scala:430)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateTree(Importers.scala:381)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importTree(Importers.scala:430)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateTree(Importers.scala:388)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importTree(Importers.scala:430)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateTree(Importers.scala:379)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importTree(Importers.scala:430)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.recreateTree(Importers.scala:397)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importTree(Importers.scala:430)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Importers$StandardImporter.importTree(Importers.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Evals.eval(Evals.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Evals.eval$(Evals.scala:26)
    at scala.reflect.macros.contexts.Context.eval(Context.scala:18)
    at org.shapesafe.m.FieldTypes$typeablePoly$.cseImpl(FieldTypes.scala:42)
```

So what's the cause of this error and how to circumvent it/

BTW, I have tried to convert this project into bloop, which seems to eliminate this compilation error. So it is likely a compiler bug, but there is very little information on it.

The compilation process can be observed at:

https://github.com/tribbloid/shapesafe/runs/2262732200?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: Again your question lacks definition of `TypeViz.infer`